# How to call another screens from one screen that have seven buttons

Tags: android

Please help me.
I have eight activities.
Suppose that A1 is first activity.
A1 has seven button.
i want to call other activities by clicking buttons From A1.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried.

Comment: Please do some search before posting here.You will get tons of examples on it.

Comment: add "startActivity(new Intent(yourclass.this, theclassyoureferingto.class)); in your onclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

```
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Home_Page);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

you have to insert intent in every button and then give the class path like I did..

Comment: @user3584725 or read this documentation you will get alot of help...
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html